# Printing out a word if it has a specific letter in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would i print out a word in a list or string that has a specific letter in it?

e.g.

Letter: e

Input: I need help with my program

need help

See how it printed out "need help" because those words have "e" in them? Help :)

My workaround:

```
a = input("Letter: ")
b = input("Input: ")
c = b.count(a)
print(c)
d = b.split()
for e in d:
  print(e,end=" ")
```

Comment: Regexp to the rescue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
a = input("Letter: ")
b = input("Input: ")
words = b.split()
for word in words:
    if a in word:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Please note the Python 3.x tag (use the `print` *function*.)

Comment: Ok i have my final code thanks for Maroun Maroun, i just need to .rstrip() the output now :)

`for word in words:
  if a in word:
    print(word.lower(),end=" ")`

How can i remove the space in the final output?

Comment: @JosephStephen You can use `"bla bla bla     ".rstrip()`

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a character (or substring) is in a string using `in`:

```
letter = input("Letter: ")[0] # Limit to one character
words = input("Text: ").split()
for word in words:
    if letter in word:
        print(word, end=" ")
print() # Add newline
```

#### Addendum (see the comments):

To remove the final space, you can accumulate the words in a string and then remove it

```
letter = input("Letter: ")[0] # Limit to one character
words = input("Text: ").split()
output = ""
for word in words:
    if letter in word:
        output += word + " "
print(output.rstrip()) # Print without trailing whitespace
```

or (*which I would discourage*, because it makes the intention less obvious) check if you are encountering the last word and print a newline instead of the additional space (so you don't need the additional `print()`.

```
letter = input("Letter: ")[0] # Limit to one character
words = input("Text: ").split()
for index in range(len(words)):
    if letter in words[index]:
        the_end = "\n" if index == len(words) - 1 else " " # Newline only if it is the last word
        print(word, end=the_end)
```

Comment: How can i rstrip the final space in the output?

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. In your `for` loop, now you just need a conditional.

A conditional is a statement which determines whether something is `True` or `False`.

You probably want:

```
for e in d:
    if a in e:
        print(e)
```